# PRISM: RegisterType gives implicit reference conversion error

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism

I have got three projects in my solution.

One holds the interface:

```
public interface ISetupData
{
    Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; } 
}
```

Another an implementation of the interface:

```
public class SetupData : ISetupData
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

The third the uses both:

```
Container.RegisterType<ISetupData, SetupData>();
```

I have set the references in the projects so everything is recognised. But when i compile i get the error:

The type SetupData cannot be used as type parameter 'TTo' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer, params Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectionMember[])'. There is no implicit reference conversion from SetupData to ISetupData.

If I put the declaration of the interface into the project of the implementation of the interface it works fine.

I don't have any idea what this error means. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you write `ISetupData x = new SetupData();` in the third project, do you get the same problem? Are you certain you don't have another `ISetupData` somewhere?

Comment: That's weird. Meanwhile have have done some changes to interface and concrete class (added a property) and I don't get the error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

So I have the following, which works for me for getting report data out of my database context - I have simplified it to just the parts I think you might be interested in:

*UnityConfig* class

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using WeeklyReport.Repository;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Unity.Mvc3;

namespace WeeklyReport
{
    public class UnityConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterContainer()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            //ensure the repository is disposed after each request by using the lifetime manager
            container.RegisterType<IDataRepository, DataRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

        }
    }
}
```

*IDataRepository* class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WeeklyReport.Models;

namespace WeeklyReport.Repository
{
    public interface IDataRepository
    { 
        IEnumerable<ReportViewModel> GetAllMetrics();
    }
}
```

and my *Repository* class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using WeeklyReport.Models;

namespace WeeklyReport.Repository
{
    public class DataRepository : IDataRepository
    {
         // ....
         public IEnumerable<ReportViewModel> GetAllMetrics()
         {
             // ....
         }
    }
}
```

I then instantiate `private readonly IDataRepository repository;` in my Controller and I can call `repository.GetAllMetrics()` in my function that returns the data to my view.

Probably goes without saying, but hopefully you added the NuGet Package *Unity*.

I originally ran across the same error you did because I forgot to add `: IDataRepository` on my DataRepository class, meaning I was not inheriting the `IDataRepository`. I see that is not the problem in your case, but that is what the error means - it means the relationship is not established and the interface cannot find its underlying covariant (`ISetupData` cannot find `SetupData`).

I do not see that you created a `UnityContainer`, but are calling `Container` directly, instead. Probably not the best practice.  And you would have needed to then do `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));` .  I would recommend creating an instance of the `UnityContainer`, not directly calling `Container`.

You said it worked when you "put the declaration of the interface into the project of the implementation of the interface"? Sorry, but that was EXTREMELY confusing and I have no idea what you meant by that.

I don't get why you are doing `{ get; set; }` on both sides. One is supposed to be the implementation for the other, and you had `Dictionary`, not `IDictionary`. It should look like this:

```
public interface ISetupData
{
    IDictionary<string, string> Data;
}
```

After instantiating `private readonly ISetupData myData;` you should be able to use `myData.Data` to mean `SetupData`.

So I think if you use that, and do:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using WeeklyReport.Repository;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Unity.Mvc3;

namespace WeeklyReport
{
    public class UnityConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterContainer()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            //ensure the repository is disposed after each request by using the lifetime manager
            container.RegisterType<ISetupData, SetupData>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

        }
    }
}
```

You should've been fine, as long as your *Global.ascx.cs* had `UnityConfig.RegisterContainer();` in the `App_Start` section.